# My HTML file can't load my PDE files in browser?

Tags: processing, processing.js

I have created a sketch file using processing.js and saved it to a pde file. I saved the processing.js source file, my html file, and my sketch pde file and get the following error in the chrome console:
"XMLHttpRequest failure, possibly due to a same-origin policy violation."

I feel that my html is correct in terms of the source integration and my pde file is saved correctly, so I'm not to sure why the html file isn't loading the sketch.
Here are my following files:

hello_web.pde:

```java
    void setup() {
    size(200, 200);
    background(100);
    stroke(255);
    ellipse(50, 50, 25, 25);
    println("hello web!");
}
```

hello_web.html:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Hello Web - Processing.js Test</title>
    <script src="processing-1.0.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Processing.js Test</h1>
    <p>This is my first Processing.js web-based 
    sketch:</p>
    <canvas data-processing-sources="hello-web.pde"> . 
    </canvas>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is because Chrome treats file:/// differently from http(s)://, and the JavaScript calling other files locally is violating the same-origin policy. So, you will need to run this from a local server so that you have the http:// in front of your address. You can read more about this on [their wiki](https://github.com/jeresig/processing-js/blob/master/README.md#loading-processingjs-sketches-locally).

If you're looking to easily launch a server, running `python -m http.server` (this is assuming Python 3, you may need to run `python -m http.server`) will serve the current directory, so just navigate to the correct directory and run that command, and then visiting http://localhost will allow you to access your files from a local server.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Unsolved Cypher's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53424298/873165), note that you can also put all of your content in a single file, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Sketch</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/processing.js/1.6.0/processing.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="application/processing">
            void setup(){
                size(200, 200);
            }

            void draw(){
                background(64);
                ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 20, 20);
            }
        </script>
        <canvas> </canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

Or you could use a free webhost, or a service like CodePen. [Here](https://codepen.io/pen?template=LRzErQ) is a template I use for Processing.js sketches on CodePen.

Shameless self-promotion: [here](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/processing-js) is a tutorial on Processing.js.